# Javascript modify response text of XHR request on specified url

Tags: javascript, request, xmlhttprequest

So I'm trying to modify the response text of a XHR request but only on a certain url.
Heres what I have:

```
(function(http){
  var get = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
    http.prototype,
    'responseText'
  ).get;

  Object.defineProperty(
    http.prototype,
    "responseText",
    {
      get: function(){ return get.apply( this, arguments ) + '{"Admin":true}'}
    }
  );
})(self.XMLHttpRequest);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters to XMLHttpRequest object:

```
var myUrl = 'https://www.google.es'
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ( xml.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(xml.url);
      if(xml.url === 'https://www.google.es'){
        //change response here
      }
    }
};
xml.open("GET", myUrl, true);
xml.url = myUrl;
xml.send();
```

Comment: yeh not what i asked for

Comment: im trying to modify the incoming requests response automatically so when a new request comes in it auto modifys but only on a certain url